# Identify this tree from Nepal

Tags: species-identification, trees

[image][image: A tree in Nepal]This is a picture of a tree in Nepal. Can somebody identify it?

Comment: Do you have some more picture of the leafes? Will be hard to identify the tree solely based on the bark

Comment: I have uploaded photo of leaf.

Comment: The leaves on the top left have different veins than the leaf from the photo, Are they from the same tree?